# Make html table like mac calendar

Tags: html, calendar, html-table

I am making a html table and there is a column to show comments.
Comments are sometimes too long to show in a small table cell,
so I want to add an effect to the column like mac calendar, when I 
click on the cell, the content will popup.

Anybody could tell me what technology can be used for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap to solve this problems, especially bootstrap popovers.

First of all, in your `script.js` or `script` tags include...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
```

In your head tags of your html, include...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

To make your popover, do this.

```
<a href="#" title="New Event Popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="These are your events">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a range of solutions for this starting from a simple 'title' attribute within an HTML element to pop-up controlled via a javascript library like jQuery.

The simple solution is shown:

```
<html...
  <table...
    <tr...
       <td><ul><li title="New Event on date 2016-Apr-10.">New Event</li></ul></td>
```

This has limitations : chiefly that that text is only formatted as as simple paragraph and the browser decides how to display it. It also is available only as you hover above the list item, NOT when you click there.

This is a good, simple solution on your way to a better, more complicated, solutions.

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery tooltip to accomplish that.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Calendar!">Calendar data here</a>
```

---

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: This provides no code that is used to solve the problem.